# slice wrapping data with xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray.DataArray with global data. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

nlat=46
nlon=90

lat=np.linspace(-90, 90, nlat, endpoint=True)
lat=xr.DataArray(lat, dims=('lat',), coords={'lat':lat}, 
    attrs={'units':'degree north', 'name':'latitude'})

lon=np.linspace(0, 360, nlon, endpoint=False)
lon=xr.DataArray(lon, dims=('lon',), coords={'lon':lon}, 
    attrs={'units':'degree east', 'name':'longitude'})

d=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(nlat, nlon), 
    dims=('lat', 'lon'), coords={'lat':lat, 'lon':lon})
```

I now want to slice the data into a region. Mostly that's easy:

```
aus = d.sel(lat=slice(-44,-10), lon=slice(110, 155))
```

The problem is areas at the wrapping border, for example:

```
gb = d.sel(lat=slice(50, 60), lon=slice(351, 3))
```

Of course, this returns an empty array, as 351>3.

At the moment, I help myself with shifting the grid, then selecting:

```
d['lon'].values[d['lon'].values>180] -= 360
d = d.sortby(d['lon'])
gb = d.sel(lat=slice(50, 60), lon=slice(-9, 3))
```

Is there no better way?

Comment: [Dataset.roll](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.roll.html) helps with the grid shifting

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid shifting the grid, there's two options that may help:

1. the [xr.DataArray.where](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html) method, with the condition specifying the desired d.lon boundaries:

```
lon_lower = 351
lon_upper = 3

%timeit d.where((d.lon > lon_lower) | (d.lon < lon_upper), drop=True)
# 1.97 ms ± 50.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

2. logical indexing along lon axis:

```
%timeit d[:,(d.lon.values > lon_lower) | (d.lon.values < lon_upper)]
# 457 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

timing of slice for comparison:

```
%timeit d.sel(lon=slice(10,30))
# 452 µs ± 13.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I was kind of hoping that there's a simple way to do it in such a way that the longitudes are in the right order afterwards (i.e. 355 coming before 0). But I guess that's too much to hope for.